# Using Lagrange multipliers to find the extrema of $f(x,y) = e^{2xy}$ subject to $x^2+y^2 = 16$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, systems-of-equations, lagrange-multiplier

> Find the maximum and minimum values of $f = e^{2xy}$ with respect to $x^2+y^2 = 16$.

Using Lagrange multipliers,
$\nabla f = \lambda\nabla g$. Therefore, the constraints are the following:

$$x^2+y^2 = 16$$
$$2ye^{2xy} = \lambda2x$$
$$2xe^{2xy} = \lambda2y$$

How would I solve this system of equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you note that $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$ you can divide the second equation by the third and get:

$$\frac{2ye^{2xy}}{2xe^{2xy}} = \frac{2\lambda x}{2\lambda y} \ ,$$
which after simplification says that $x^2=y^2$. Taking the first equation, you can then write
$$x^2 + y^2 = 2x^2 = 16$$
This gives $x=\pm 2\sqrt{2}$ and therefore four possible solutions $(x,y)=(\pm 2\sqrt{2},\pm 2\sqrt{2})$, where all sign combinations are possible.